# Why I cannot see the open graph action in my news feed in Facebook?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I am posting an Facebook OpenGraph action called "recommend". I can see that in the app's activity, but not in the friend's news feed. What is the reason? Is it because the action is not published to Facebook(still in development)?

Comment: Have your actions been approved by Facebook?

Comment: Yep, only developers of the app will see unapproved "activities".  At least that's what I read somewhere at one time.

Comment: Yes, I can see my activities, but in the Application frame, not in the news feed of me.

Comment: Correct, that's the difference between "activity" feed and "news" feed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing is wrong.  Once Facebook has approved your actions/objects, the activities should show up on activity feed of all your friends.  The more popular activities might even appear on the wall/feed if the algorithm gods like you that day.